# Would Poly1305-PBKDF2 be secure

Tags: authentication, integrity

I have a Poly1305-implementation (**not** Poly1305-AES) in my library.

The difference: Poly1305-AES uses a key and a nonce and then uses AES to generate a one-time-key from key + nonce. This is necessary, because Poly1305 requires **one-time-keys**.
However if you are generating a unique random key anyway, you can leave out the AES-part. ([short source](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/poly1305), [original source](http://cr.yp.to/mac/poly1305-20050329.pdf))

---

**My question:** Is it secure to generate a unique one-time-key from a static key using another KDF with unique salt (like PBKDF2)?

(I think you could call this Poly1305-PBKDF2 or sth. like this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this would be secure.

Why would it be secure?
Because you would be running HMAC (the underlying primitive of PBKDF) as a stream-cipher using some key-derivation function.
As this is a common approach (at least for integrated encryption schemes) using this would at least as secure as using the bare KDF and a salt.

However I'd **strongly argue against** using PBKDF2 for anything but password-based key derivation and as a "stream cipher" it would give people a wrong sense of security (because it's 1000x slower = 10 bits more security).

If you want to use Poly-1305 I'd recommend you using a dedicated stream cipher (e.g. ChaCha20) or a dedicated stream cipher mode (e.g. CTR).

Comment: Well ChaCha20 is also available in the lib, so I think I will use this. Thank you :)